# Does Kuro Sakuragawa from Kyokou Suiri age?

Tags: kyokou-suiri

I mean he told that he ate both Kudan and Ningyo at age eleven, but keeps himself from aging because he dies when he predicts the future. So, what causes him to age?

What I mean to say is, if he stops future prediction, does he get older then?

Comment: Edited the question. Feel free to revert back in case I misunderstood what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Kuro Sakuragawa does age. I am guessing you got the idea from the fact that he ate two yokai making him immortal. This is meaning that he can not die form physical attacks or aging.

his physical appearances does change form when he was young, and when they show us his memories form when he was young this shows that his physical appearance does change with time.

note: I am saying he can't die form physical attacks or aging. there is nothing stating that there is some magic that can truly kill him and there is nothing saying that it can happen. it's just a thought .

Comment: So he will just be a frail old immortal who can't die or move due to old age in future ?
that's sad, really sad.